# authorization code grant flow but without browser

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Have to implement an app that gets username/password of Azure AD user from command line and obtain an access token to query ms graph. The AD application is created and configured to require MFA - it is a must (username/password flow is not an option).
I can use authorization code grant flow but that involves to open a browser and provide the user credentials but I don't want open a form an fill the credentials, I want to provide them internally (obtained from the user as app params). let's suppose that I use this app after I have ssh to a server. User should authorize this login by an authorizer app (MFA).
Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: May i know can you use  RestAPI(postman) to access the ms Graph?

Answer (score 0):

The only flow that allows you to take credentials is the ROPC flow, which does not support MFA.

Device code flow could be an option if this is a console app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code.
This flow gives the user a code that they need to enter in a browser that they can open on any device.
To me this feels like the best option.